# How can I bind to the change event of a textarea in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to capture if any changes happened to `<textarea>`. Like typing any characters (deleting,backspace) or mouse click and paste or cut.  Is there a jQuery event that can trigger for all those events?

I tried change event, but it triggers the callback only after tabbing out from the component.

**Use**: I want to enable a button if a `<textarea>` contains any text.

Comment: Binding to key events is not enough because text can be changed by mouse ("paste"/"cut" from context menu or drag&drop).

Comment: Similar question is discussed in [Textarea onchange detection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823733/textarea-onchange-detection).

Answer (score 366, accepted):

Try this actually:

```
$('#textareaID').bind('input propertychange', function() {

      $("#yourBtnID").hide();

      if(this.value.length){
        $("#yourBtnID").show();
      }
});
```

## [DEMO](http://output.jsbin.com/ikeses/200/edit?html,css,js,output)

That works for any changes you make, typing, cutting, pasting.

Comment: I think it works only in IE. Found from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988660/propertychange-event-is-not-available-in-firefox

Comment: @Senthilnathan: No works in Chrome and FF as well for me because it is just not `propertychange` there is also `input`

Comment: Beware as I just dicsovered that neither of these two events fire in IE9 (haven't checked older versions of IE) when the backspace key is pressed in a textarea.

Comment: "stack overflow on line x" in IE8.

Comment: Its not working in ie9, works in 7-8-10. Also use 'on' instead of 'bind',

Comment: These demos are using `<input type="text">`, not `<textarea>`

Comment: Change 'input propertychange' to 'input change' so that it works in IE9 as well. http://paulbakaus.com/2012/06/14/propertychange-on-internet-explorer-9/

Comment: I see you used <input type="textarea" cols="10" rows="4" /> in the DEMO, seriously?

Comment: doesn't seem to detect value changes with `$(textarea).val('set value');`

Answer (score 160):

`bind` is deprecated. Use `on`:

```
$("#textarea").on('change keyup paste', function() {
    // your code here
});
```

Note: The code above will fire multiple times, once for each matching trigger-type. To handle that, do something like this:

```
var oldVal = "";
$("#textarea").on("change keyup paste", function() {
    var currentVal = $(this).val();
    if(currentVal == oldVal) {
        return; //check to prevent multiple simultaneous triggers
    }

    oldVal = currentVal;
    //action to be performed on textarea changed
    alert("changed!");
});
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6bt2g/)

Comment: the ```on("change", function() ....``` part is not working for me. Doesn't trigger any alert, nor console logs, anything. For keyup works like a charm, though.

Comment: @Sebastialonso: The `on("change", function() ... ` is **only fired when the textarea loses focus**. Refer my [earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17317465/jquery-textbox-change-event-doesnt-fire-until-textbox-loses-focus) for this, and try it out on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6bt2g/55/) -- change the textarea, then click outside the textarea, and you should see the change event firing.

Comment: @SNag that code not working on Chrome 45, but it's working on FF 41

Comment: If you're stuck using jQuery prior to version 1.7, though, then this does not apply

Comment: upvoting for use on non deprecated function.  Much better than .bind()

Comment: Event "kye" will trigger everytime enter any character in textarea. My suggestion better to have "change" and "paste"

Comment: keyup can be arrows

Comment: You might just use `.one("change keyup paste", function ...` instead of `.on`. The `one` eventlistener fires only once.

Comment: @solitud I tried `.one()` [here](https://jsfiddle.net/54g8yrvj/) but it stops firing after the first character and doesn't fire for every subsequent character change or paste. Can you verify?

Comment: @SNag That is the intended behaviour. If the text changes it should only fire once e.g. to make the submit button visible via an added css class. Not necessary to apply the CSS class on every consecutive keystroke.
You can wrap the event listener in a function so you can call the function again after someone clicked the *submit* button to reactivate the listener for the next single keystroke.

Comment: it doesn't seem like this handles paste events? thanks for your help.

Comment: @Crashalot Are you sure you included the `paste` verb? `.on("change keyup paste") ...`?

Comment: "change the textarea, then click outside the textarea, and you should see the change event firing. – SNag Jun 5 '14 at 5:11"
Is it possible to avoid this?
Is there a way to make it trigger while still inside the textarea?

Comment: @bieboebap: Yes, you can achieve that with `.on("keyup")`. Also experiment with `keydown` and `keypress` to see which one suits your particular usecase best. This [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3396754/979621) discusses the differences in the event firing behaviour.

Answer (score 96):

Use an [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) event.

```
var button = $("#buttonId");
$("#textareaID").on('input',function(e){
  if(e.target.value === ''){
    // Textarea has no value
    button.hide();
  } else {
    // Textarea has a value
    button.show();
  }
});
```

Comment: For Internet Explorer, this requires 9+, or even 10+ to function properly.

Comment: This solution works like a charm.
Perfectly overcomes the limitatins of change() and keypress() event handlers. Thanks a ton forks.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for paste events? thanks for your help.

Comment: @Crashalot Actually it works perfectly fine for typing, *pasting**, deleting with both a keyboard and a mouse. Just tested this with the latest (at the time of writing this comment) versions of Chrome, Firefox and Edge.

Answer (score 27):

This question needed a more up-to-date answer, with sources. This is what *actually* works (though you don't have to take my word for it):

```
// Storing this jQuery object outside of the event callback 
// prevents jQuery from having to search the DOM for it again
// every time an event is fired.
var $myButton = $("#buttonID")

// input           :: for all modern browsers [1]
// selectionchange :: for IE9 [2]
// propertychange  :: for <IE9 [3]
$('#textareaID').on('input selectionchange propertychange', function() {

  // This is the correct way to enable/disabled a button in jQuery [4]
  $myButton.prop('disabled', this.value.length === 0)

}
```

1: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input#Browser_compatibility 
2: [oninput in IE9 doesn't fire when we hit BACKSPACE / DEL / do CUT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382389/oninput-in-ie9-doesnt-fire-when-we-hit-backspace-del-do-cut#answer-13780757) 
3: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536956(v=vs.85).aspx 
4: http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop-propertyName-function

**BUT, for a more global solution that you can use throughout your project**, I recommend using [the textchange jQuery plugin](https://github.com/spicyj/jquery-splendid-textchange) to gain a new, cross-browser compatible `textchange` event. It was developed by [the same person](http://benalpert.com/2013/06/18/a-near-perfect-oninput-shim-for-ie-8-and-9.html) who implemented the equivalent `onChange` event for Facebook's ReactJS, which they use for nearly their entire website. And I think it's safe to say, if it's a robust enough solution for Facebook, it's probably robust enough for you. :-)

**UPDATE:** If you happen to need features like drag and drop support in Internet Explorer, you may instead want to check out [`pandell`'s more recently updated fork of `jquery-splendid-textchange`](https://github.com/pandell/jquery-splendid-textchange).

Comment: Though it seems "selectionchange" works only when applied to the document. Active element could be gotten with "document.activeElement".

Answer (score 14):

### 2018, without JQUERY

*The question is **with** JQuery, it's just FYI.*

#### JS

```
let textareaID = document.getElementById('textareaID');
let yourBtnID = document.getElementById('yourBtnID');
textareaID.addEventListener('input', function() {
    yourBtnID.style.display = 'none';
    if (textareaID.value.length) {
        yourBtnID.style.display = 'inline-block';
    }
});
```

#### HTML

```
<textarea id="textareaID"></textarea>
<button id="yourBtnID" style="display: none;">click me</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for paste events? thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

Here's another (modern) but slightly different version than the ones mentioned before. Tested with IE9:

```
$('#textareaID').on('input change keyup', function () {
  if (this.value.length) {
    // textarea has content
  } else {
    // textarea is empty
  }
});
```

For outdated browsers you might also add `selectionchange` and `propertychange` (as mentioned in other answers). But `selectionchange` didn't work for me in IE9. That's why I added `keyup`.

Answer (score 2):

try this ...

```
$("#txtAreaID").bind("keyup", function(event, ui) {                          

              // Write your code here       
 });
```

Comment: Binding to key events is not enough because text can be changed by mouse ("paste"/"cut" from context menu or drag&drop).

Answer (score 2):

Try to do it with focusout

```
$("textarea").focusout(function() {
   alert('textarea focusout');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**.delegate** is the only one that is working to me with *jQuery JavaScript Library v2.1.1*

```
 $(document).delegate('#textareaID','change', function() {
          console.log("change!");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

After some experimentation I came up with this implementation:

```
$('.detect-change')
    .on('change cut paste', function(e) {
        console.log("Change detected.");
        contentModified = true;
    })
    .keypress(function(e) {
        if (e.which !== 0 && e.altKey == false && e.ctrlKey == false && e.metaKey == false) {
            console.log("Change detected.");
            contentModified = true;
        }
    });
```

Handles changes to any kind of input and select as well as textareas ignoring arrow keys and things like ctrl, cmd, function keys, etc.

Note: I've only tried this in FF since it's for a FF add-on.

Answer (score -11):

Try this

```
 $('textarea').trigger('change');
 $("textarea").bind('cut paste', function(e) { });
```

Comment: this is not completely wrong. In fact if one combines `$("#textarea").on('change keyup paste', function() {})` and `$('textarea').trigger('change');` can address the issue that prevents to `paste` to work automatically!