# Trigger the change of text in text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, textbox

I am unable to trigger the change of the text in the current scenario.

If i click on the button i am changing the content of the text. So how can i trigger the change of the text which is caused by external event.
For example in a click of a button I can able to fill any text in the textbox, able to paste texts and using mouse and keyboard. In these all scenarios and scenarios like these also I want the event to be fired.

I have already tried the following.

```
$('#text_id').on('change', function () {
    alert('This is not trigged when i changed the text');
});
```

The alert should come when the text is changed. There might be many possible sources to change the text.

This is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/upa2A/) i created.

Thanks in advance.

This is my updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/upa2A/8/)

Answer (score 1):

Updated Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/upa2A/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', "#button_id", function () {
        $('#text_id').val('TExt changed')
    });

    $(document).on('change', "#text_id", function () {
        alert('This is not trigged when i changed the text');
    });
});
```

**Issues in original Fiddle** -

- Code has to be inside `$(document).ready()`
- Missing `()` after `function`
- Incorrect use of `$.on` (Read more about it on http://api.jquery.com/on/)

**Edit based on comment from asked** -

Updated Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/upa2A/4/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', "#button_id", function () {
        $('#text_id').val('TExt changed').change();
    });

    $(document).on('change', "#text_id", function () {
        alert('This is not trigged when i changed the text');
    });
});
```

**More edit based on comments thread** -

From http://api.jquery.com/change "but for the other element types the event is deferred until the element loses focus."

Since, when changing via button click, text box wasn't focussed, the trigger does not happen automatically.

Comment: Sorry your fiddle is not triggering the change of the text. Could you please check

Comment: It is for me... Did you change your own fiddle or used the link I gave? Because your Fiddle didn't had JQuery library added.

Comment: @user3354774, that link works for me (and for Somnath). Check your browser console and let us know, if you see any errors.

Comment: @HarshMoorjani you are triggering manually as $('#text_id').val('TExt changed').change(). The alert come naturally when the text is changed in the text box

Comment: @user3354774, Type anything in the box and move out of box. It will. But when you edit if via js, you need to trigger it.

Comment: We wont change the text manually that would be changed in many ways i showed one example of on clicking the button.

Comment: @user3354774, in that case you can trigger in along with change. As you can see from - http://api.jquery.com/change/ "`but for the other element types the event is deferred until the element loses focus.`" Now, since when changing via click you never had focus, so its not triggered.

Comment: @HarshMoorjani Yeah i observed that one is there any way to accomplish my task

Comment: @user3354774 - In that case, this becomes the right answer. Please accept it :-)

Comment: @HarshMoorjani but that didn't meet my requirement. I should get the alert when the text is changed but you are manually triggering it ...

Comment: @user3354774 - Ok, but as I said - it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I saw your code in jsfiddle. you missed in some brackets and semicolon . otherwise   ur code write . pls check jquery library code.

```
$('#button_id').on('click',function()
               {
                   $('#text_id').val('TExt changed');
               }
              );
```

$('#text_id').on('change',function() {  alert('This is not trigged when i changed the text');
                 } );

Comment: @SomnathKharat Can you please suggest me what are the mistakes i made in my fiddle

Comment: First select library code in your fiddle. put bracket for fuction()

Comment: "if i click on the button i am changing the content of the text. So how can i trigger the change of the text which is caused by external event." not only on click of button by any means

Comment: put this code "   $('#text_id').val('TExt changed'); " on textid on change function

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code. But for this you should use jQuery. It'll raise the event whenever the text changed.

```
$('#text_id').on('input propertychange paste', function() {
    alert('Text Changed');
});
```

the working fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/upa2A/10/)

Comment: The alert must come when the text is changed by other event not on keyup ... like clicking on the button the text is changed that is one of the example ..

Comment: @user3354774 these are the basic things of text changing events described in all answers. If you want to implement a specific logic you have to use your brain to bring out that by these basic ideas.

Comment: @user3354774 I can, but it's look like you are not taking any steps at all.

Comment: @user3354774 See my updated answer and working fiddle

Comment: How about if i added some event to button and changed the text on click that is not giving the alert http://jsfiddle.net/upa2A/11/

Answer (score 0):

This event surely raised on text change. If it is not useful for you surely someone else will be happy for this.

```
var txtVal = '';
setInterval(function() {
    if ($("#text_id").val() != txtVal) {
        txtVal = $("#text_id").val();
        alert("Text Changed");
    }
}, 10);
```

working fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/upa2A/13/)

Comment: I took this code piece from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17317465/jquery-textbox-change-event-doesnt-fire-until-textbox-loses-focus. It's a nice answer. You please refer it.