# Jquery textbox string length function

Tags: jquery, textbox

I am trying to get a function to work so that I get an alert (for now!) when a user has entered a four character code into a text box.

I'm using...

```
$(window).load(function () {
$("#textbox").on('input', function () {
    if ($("#textbox").val().length > 3) {
        alert("Four characters detected!");
    }
});
```

});

I must be missing something, as the alert doesn't fire. JSFiddle at: 
http://jsfiddle.net/1s8phz4w/

TIA
JV

Comment: Change .load() to .ready()

Comment: this one will also work http://jsfiddle.net/vnodkumar1987/1s8phz4w/2/

Comment: its working just instead of `window.load` use `document.ready` see here http://jsfiddle.net/1s8phz4w/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the 'input' event is not the one you're seeking.

Try 'change' or 'keyup' :

```
$(document).on('ready', function () {
    $('#textbox').on('change keyup', function () {
        if (this.value.length > 3) {
            alert("Four characters detected!");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I went for the 'input' event as it covers a number of different types on input including right-click paste etc. as I found here: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17317465/jquery-textbox-change-event-doesnt-fire-until-textbox-loses-focus

Answer (score 0):

Probably your js is loading before the element. Prevent this using `$(document).ready(function(){ your code here });`

This will trigger your function only after your page is fully loaded.