# jQuery input type text not firing keyup event

Tags: jquery, textbox

As in the title i'm trying to make add  AJAX to search box on my site but keyup event not firing. I'm using function from this message https://stackoverflow.com/a/17317620/5690756

Anyway here is my code

```
<nav id="search" class="search-main">
    <div class="search-trigger"></div>
    <div class="search-general">
        <div class="search-close"></div>
        <input type="text" value="" id="autocomplete" name="s" class="search-input ui-autocomplete-input" placeholder="Arama" autocomplete="off">
        <input type="button" class="search-button">
```

And js code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$("#autocomplate").on('change keyup paste', function() {
    alert("Girdim");
    var lastValue = $("#autocomplate").val();
            jQuery.ajax({
                type : 'post',
                url : helper.ajaxUrl,
                data : {action : 'load_search_results',query : lastValue
                },
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
                },
                success : function( response ) {
                    $(this).prop('disabled', false);
                    $('#modal_results').html( response );
                }
            });
        
});
});
```

Alert function not working in my code how can i solve this issue i have no idea.

Edit:
I have another function for parent element. Can it block input function also i added html code to the beginning for to be clear.

```
$("#search").click(function () {
    if($(this).attr("class")=="search-main"){
        $(this).attr("class","search-main expand");
        $("#autocomplete").attr("placeholder","Lütfen dizi, oyuncu veya tür adı yazın.");
        $("#autocomplete").focus();
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: it works here http://jsfiddle.net/tg5op333/9/  see your console if there is any errors

Comment: is #autocomplate input part of HTML when the page is loading or it gets appended to the HTML after the page is loaded ?

Comment: No it is header.php file on wordpress and there is no error on console. I disabled cache on developer console and no result

Comment: I updated question i have another function for parent div click event can it block input change event ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mistyped `autocomplate` it does not match with id `autocomplete` .

Comment: I can't believe that i didn't see it. I'm looking this for 2 hours lol