# jquery form change for textarea, radio

Tags: jquery

I will need to detect if **ALL** form change for all element,

I tried

```
$('input, select').change(function(){
  alert(' work! ');
});

$('#formID').change(function(){
  alert(' work too !');
});

$('textarea, input[type=radio]').change(function(){
  alert(' Wont fire ?? ');
});
```

How do I detect change on textarea, radio button and checkbox ?

Comment: works fine  - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/1dhqnxag/1/

Comment: look like I have some other jquery preventing such change

Comment: could be... but since the handlers are attached to the element's itself the only reason for it to not fire is if there is a call to [event.stopImmediatePropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation/) or you are creating those elements in a dynamic way after the handler registration code is executed(in such case have a look at [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/))

Comment: I added $(document).on('change', 'input', function() {  console.log(' but no luck') });  anyway thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#textareaID').bind('input propertychange', function() {

      $("#yourBtnID").hide();

      if(this.value.length){
        $("#yourBtnID").show();
      }
});
```

Which is copied form [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11338644/2630817)

and for radio button change

```
$("input[name=someRadioGroup]:radio").change(function () {
```

Answer (score 0):

## 1. Assign unique id (ex: id="sampleName") to textarea and common name to the necessary radio buttons (ex: name="sampleName")

## 2. Use the following Jquery stuff,

```
$('#sampleName').change(function(){
  alert(' work!');
});

$("input[name=sampleName]:radio").change(function(){
  alert(' work!');
});
```