# Detecting changes in textarea with dynamically-binded data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, data-binding, dom-events

I want to detect when the content of a `<textarea>` element has changed. For changes done by the user, I can use solutions in these questions:

1. [How can I bind to the change event of a textarea in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11338592/2317532)
2. [Textarea onchange detection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2823733/2317532)

which detects keypresses, pastes events etc. But what if the data is data-bound dynamically, for example using frameworks such as AngularJS, MeteorJS etc. I must then add a function to be ran in the frameworks alongside the data-binding functions.

Is there a Javascript or jQuery method / event listener that I can use to detect content change, without adding it in the framework?

Comment: Do the frameworks have an event that fires when an event is bound? If so listen for that and find all the elements and trigger the change event.

Comment: @epascarello I'm sure different frameworks have different ways to do this. I am looking for a non-framework-specific method. Just because sometimes you inherit a project and deadlines are tight, it's not practical to RTFM for the framework, even though that might be the best solution. Sometimes I just want to eat dinner.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-jquery-dom-change-listener

Answer (score 0):

You can use setInterval
This is an example with jQuery :

Html

```
 <textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
<a href="#" id="link">change text dynamicly</a>
<span id="status"></span>
```

Javascript

```
$(function(){
    $('#textarea').data('old',$('#textarea').val())
    $('#link').on('click',function(){
          $('#textarea').val('text changed dynamicly');
        return false;
    })
    setInterval(function() { 
        if($('#textarea').val() != $('#textarea').data('old')){
            $('#status').html('text of textarea is changed to : ' + $('#textarea').val())
        }
         $('#textarea').data('old',$('#textarea').val())
    }, 100);
})
```

this is a demo in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7gL78aue/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it doesn't seem to work. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u3u1yus9/2/).

Comment: i updated my code, and this is an example in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7gL78aue/