# jquery .on('input') doesn't get fired in ie8 alone

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I'm having this issue specific to IE8. This event doesn't fire in IE8 alone, but is working fine in IE9 and other browsers like Firefox and Chrome.

```
$('#myId').on('input', function () {
   //do something.
}
```

Please let me know if there is any work around for the same in IE8.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't recognize "input" as an event trigger, myself. Maybe I've just never seen it?

Comment: Try using `change` or `keyup` instead, `input` isn't supported in older browsers.

Comment: @VoidKing and everyone that upvoted your comment: Learn about it: [MDN oninput](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.oninput)

Comment: On a side note make sure you aren't using jquery 2.0+ it doesn't support old IE versions.

Comment: The `input` event is a new event, is't not supported in IE8

Comment: keyup works fine. change works only the textbox looses focus. thanks

Comment: oninput fire for more than just key events.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect when a text input changes with ie8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11791855/how-to-detect-when-a-text-input-changes-with-ie8)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

oninput is IE9+, that is why it does not work in IE8

**[MDN `oninput`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.oninput)**

```
Feature         Chrome    Firefox    Internet Explorer    Opera    Safari
Basic support   (Yes)     2          9                    10       (Yes)
```

Comment: Note that IE9 also doesn't support `oninput` well, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382389/oninput-in-ie9-doesnt-fire-when-we-hit-backspace-del-do-cut

Answer (score 27):

Older versions of IE have an event called `propertychange` that you can use. You can check for the `propertychange` event and the `input` event at the same time:

```
$('#myId').on("propertychange input",function(ev){
    doAwesomeThing();
});
```

Comment: Works but fires property change event twice in IE8 ... used `'keyup input'` instead and it worked!

Comment: Confirmed, Justin's solution above works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

AaronBaker's answer: Works for both IE8 and IE10(html5) as well as modern browsers... without double post of event

I would have used comment or upvote but rep too low.

```
$('#myId').on("propertychange input",function(ev){
    doAwesomeThing();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `input` event is a part of the HTML5 specification, something I wouldn't expect IE8 to handle.  You may need to use the `change` event instead.

Answer (score 1):

This slight optimization will prevent the listener from firing twice in modern browsers (kind of a hack, but prob the best solution)

$('selector').on(!window.eventListener ? 'keyup' : 'input', function () {}

Answer (score 0):

I tried using `propertychange` as suggested by the top answer, but I noticed that sometimes it doesn't fire in IE8. For example after a page refresh with a prefilled input if I delete only one character.

My solution is to use `keyup cut paste` events instead of `propertychange`:

```
$('#myId').on('input keyup cut paste', function(e) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        doAwesomeThing();
    }, 0);
});
```

I used `setTimeout` with 0 delay because otherwise I would get the old input value on `cut` and `paste` events, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/9364812/2324685 for details.

You should note that this code might fire twice in some cases.